# How to make responsive clickable image/video like SagmeisterAndWalsh.com?

Tags: background-image

I want to make a responsive site that has an image with links you can click.

[This site](http://www.sagmeisterwalsh.com/) has invisible divs that sync up with the picture even as the image scales and resizes with the browser.

I want to first try to do the same thing with an image, and then I want to try it with a video.

Are they using any scss or javasript to make that happen, or are they just using css and html?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using just CSS and HTML, I've made a quick JSFiddle with a full size image background and a little nav.
As with the links you make the text on the image, then create a div ontop of them, don't set a background and just use a border until you get them in the correct place.

https://jsfiddle.net/2mow8qhv/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="bgHeader"></header>
        <nav id="topNav">
            <a href="#description">Description</a> | <a href="#gallery"> Gallery </a> | <a href="#map"> Map</a> |
            <a href="#comments">Comments</a>
        </nav>
            <div id="pageWrapper">
                <div id="description">
    <body>
</html>

/* Set all padding and margins to 0 by default, and colour to a grey unless overwritten*/
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #333;
}

/* HEADER AND NAVIGATION*/ 

/* Sets a background image to fill 100% of the screen and fixes it in place*/ 
header#bgHeader{
    background-image:url("http://seattlebubble.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Weyerhaeuser-Mansion_Tacoma.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
}
/* Sets the navigation menu to the bottom of the page, and layered above the image*/ 
nav#topNav{
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 55px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-align: center;
}#topNav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}#topNav a:hover{
    color: #CCC;
}
```